# Powershell SQL create db, user, and add user to owner

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am fairly new to powershell and I am trying to create a script that creates a sql database, creates a user with password, and then adds that user to be the owner of the newly created database. The script will create the database but when I go into the users I do not see 'TestUser' there.

```
#load assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
#Need SmoExtended for backup
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($server, 'TestDB2')
$db.Create()

$login = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login($server, 'TestUser')
$login.LoginType = 'SqlLogin'
$login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = $false
$login.Create('PasswordGoesHere')



$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$db = $server.Databases.Item('TestDB')
$db.SetOwner('TestUser', $TRUE)
$db.Alter()
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [SQL Server DSC resource](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServerDsc/12.0.0.0) for this task?  It would be simpler than trying to script it out.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18610/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-database-owner#18616

Answer (score 2):

You won't see the user in the database because the owner of the database cannot be a user in the database. You can see this in SSMS if you try to make an existing user in the database the owner - you will receive an error that the 'proposed database owner is mapped as a user on this database'.

[image]

With powershell, this message isn't thrown, it just unmaps the user behind the scenes - so if you had previously seen the user in the database, you no longer would once you made it the owner. This isn't what you're experiencing, though because you never create the user in the database. You're just seeing the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost always simpler to use TSQL and String Interpolation to do SQL Server administration than SMO.  EG:

```
$userName = "SomeUser"
$dbName = "newdb"
$password = "*******"

$sql = @"
create login [$userName] with password = '$password';
create database [$dbName];
alter authorization on database::[$dbName] to [$userName];
"@

$sql
invoke-sqlcmd $sql
```

Comment: Whilst I advocate the use of T-SQL statements for this job; string interpolation is **not** the way to do it. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: This is a powershell script, not a end-user program, so presumably the string inputs are coming from a trusted person.  And SQL Server does not support parameterization of DDL.  So one way or another, you're building a dynamic TSQL batch.